# How to paint wave shapes in a digital medium?

Tags: krita, painting

If you watch this video at 7:50:

https://youtu.be/VjCGJb5ltZM?t=470

[image]

You can see that the artist uses a flat brush, which she tilts to create a shape that is narrow at the beginning, then it widens, and then it tapers again.
That's very effective in making those wave shapes.

**How would you reproduce that, or something that has the same effect, in a digital medium?**

Note that I am using krita, and my tablet is not tilt-sensitive (I am not doing this professionally).

Comment: You would do it much the same way, you dont need your brush to tilt by tilting just keep it horisontal and drive the tilt with pressure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you would actually need to have tilt sensitivity for this.  Personally, I think I'd just use pressure to vary the width of the stroke. Might take a little practice.

This is using Krita and a Wacom without tilt

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What brush was that? And did you activate the 'brush smoothing' (stabiliser)?

Comment: @user6376297 Just a small default round brush, with the stabilizer. It's tricky though. Might be a way to speed it up by creating a custom shaped wave brush you can just stamp wherever you need it.

Comment: @user6376297, working digitally also allows you to erase things without consequences. So you could make the blockiest line and chip away at it with a similar eraser brush to make the shape look exactly like you want... That and or a smudge brush...

Comment: @Joonas - yup, keep your finger over that Ctrl+Z and redo as often as you want.

Comment: It might help if you stretched the brush so that its slightly wider thsn tall

Comment: Perhaps I cooked up something that sort of works. I started with 'f) Bristles-5 Flat', changed the opacity pressure sensitivity to a straight ascending line gradient, and set the Flow/Rotation/Pressure sensitivity to a gradient starting at 0 for lowest pressure and rising to 90 for highest pressure. So the brush stroke starts flat when I press gently, and rotates as I press more. In fact when I wrote 'tilt' in my post, I should have written 'rotate'. I'm sure this can be improved, but that's the best I can come up with for now.

Comment: @user6376297 sounds cool. Maybe you could write that into an answer showing how to set it up. Remember you can answer your own questions here, and even choose your own answer as best.

Comment: Credit where credit's due: you suggested to use pressure sensitivity, and my solution used that.

Answer (score 1):

You have already got some good suggestions of how to use pressure sensitivity and you've proposed something also by yourself.

I suggest you to check another free program: Inkscape. From there you can copy and paste vector shapes directly Krita and they become in Krita as vector shape layers. They can be used as perfect selections to paint fills. You can have pressure sensitive color and texture variations, but the color stays inside the selection.

Of course, the same could be done fully inside Krita, so why Inkscape?

Answer: Inkscape's vector drawing tools are much more flexible. You could draw those wave patterns in Inkscape very easily with the pen or pencil, maybe using pattern along path to get several varied versions of the same basic form and, of course, there's the calligraphic pen and numerous other vector tools.

You can paste from Krita the already painted part to be used as a reference - only remember to lock it in the layers panel.

An example.

These shapes are in Inkscape. Actually only the selected one is drawn by doing a few pen clicks. It's a not so perfect attempt to replicate a waveform shown in the video. The others are more or less distorted copies:

[image]

The shapes are pasted to Krita and converted to a selection mask for a painting layer. The painting layer has only 2 gradients. The selection is used to darken a part of the image;

[image]

Filter > Adjust Color Curves is applied to the selection to make it darker.